# Some help with prepositions in my Thesis Title

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I'm not quite sure if this is the correct StackExchange. I'm working on the title for my Master-Thesis (CS) and the prepostions look a little bit weird to me.

My title would be:

> New approaches for/to Min-Error Triangulations for Sea Surface Reconstruction

For me the "to" would feel strange, but if it should be "for", I would like to circumvent the second "for". My idea for that would be

> New approaches for Min-Error Triangulations applied to Sea Surface Reconstruction

but that also sounds off to me.
Any help  would be appreciated

Comment: We do say _an approach to_, don't we? I don't know why that sounds odd to you.

Comment: I'm German and in German we would say "für" which most of the time is translated to for. Maybe that's why

Comment: As @user405662 says 'approach to' is more normal in English. I think it's related to the idea that in the physical world we 'approach closer to' a building, landmark, person and so on.  We also say that we "make an approach to" someone if we want their support or help. We would not say that we "approached for them". Just one of the differences between German and English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To supports verbs and for supports nouns.

So...

> New approaches for Min-Error Triangulations for Sea Surface
> Reconstruction

is perfectly alright, but since you'd like to avoid two for(s) here... I'm listing a couple of alternatives below.

> New approaches employing Min-Error Triangulations for Sea Surface
> Reconstruction

Here, employing takes the place of for without altering the meaning and also making it more formal.

> New approaches to Minimize Errors in Triangulations for Sea Surface
> Reconstruction

I'm not sure if this one sounds technically right, but I've put it anyway.